# REST seems to reject JSON POST

Tags: c#, json, rest

I'm trying to POST data in JSON format but the server is rejecting it.  It works if I POST in XML and it will reply in either XML or JSON.

The contract is

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    // One string data
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        UriTemplate = "data")]
    string DataPost(Hidden param);
}

// If you get a compilation error, add
// System.Runtime.Serialization to the references
[DataContract(Name = "Hidden", Namespace = "")]
public class Hidden
{
    [DataMember]
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

The implementation is

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public string DataPost(Hidden param)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DataPost " + param.id);
        return "DataPost said " + param.id;
    }
}
```

On the client side, it is the run of the mill standard stuff.

```
namespace client
{
enum HttpVerb
{
    GET,
    POST,
    PUT,
    DELETE
};

class RestClient
{
    // Properties
    public string EndPoint { get; set; }
    public HttpVerb Method { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string ParamData { get; set; }
    public string PostData { get; set; }

    // Methods
    public string MakeRequest()
    {
        var responseValue = string.Empty;
        string ep = EndPoint;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParamData))
            ep += "/" + ParamData;
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ep);
        request.Method = Method.ToString();
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = ContentType;

        // Postdata parameters
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostData) && Method == HttpVerb.POST)
        {
            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(PostData);
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (var postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            if (PostData.Substring(0, 1) != "<")
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
            Console.WriteLine("Content type is " + request.ContentType.ToString());
        }

        // Send request and get response
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            // Did it work?
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var message = String.Format("Request failed.  Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }

            // get response
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return responseValue;
    }

    void TalkTo(
        HttpVerb in_method,
        string in_endPoint,
        string in_paramdata,
        string in_postdata)
    {
        Method = in_method;
        EndPoint = in_endPoint;
        ContentType = "text/xml";
        ParamData = in_paramdata;
        PostData = in_postdata;

        try
        {
            string response = MakeRequest();
            Console.WriteLine("Endpoint: " + EndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Resp    : " + response);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Endpoint: " + EndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Failed  : " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RestClient me = new RestClient();
        string endPointPrefix = @"http://localhost:8000/";
        me.TalkTo(
            HttpVerb.POST,
            endPointPrefix + "data",
            "",
            "<Hidden><id>xml works</id></Hidden>");

        string post = "{\"id\":\"json works\"}";
        Console.WriteLine("Json string is [" + post + "]");
        me.TalkTo(
            HttpVerb.POST,
            endPointPrefix + "data",
            "",
            post);

        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to terminate");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

On the client side, I'm getting

```
Content type is text/xml
Endpoint: http://localhost:8000/data
Resp    : <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">DataPost said xml works</string>

Json string is [{"id":"json works"}]
Content type is application/json
Endpoint: http://localhost:8000/data
Failed  : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Press <Enter> to terminate
```

When I look at the help, it says that JSON format is allowable but when I try it, it falls over.  The trace from the sever debug seems to imply that it is ignoring the application/json and just assuming that everything is xml.

```
Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Message: There was an error checking start element of object of type System.String. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Last few lines of stack trace
System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.IsStartObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader)
System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.IsStartObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message message)
```

All the examples I've looked at on SO and other sites don't add anything special so is it not working because I'm using the VS2013 express?

**EDIT** It also happens on VS2013 Web Express

**EDIT2** Doesn't look like it is isolated to express versions - I've just tried it on VS2010 Professional.  It is still using the XMLObjectSerializer to parse JSON and failing miserably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to no convert the PostData to bytes

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostData) && Method == HttpVerb.POST)
        {
            if (PostData.Substring(0, 1) != "<")
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
            Console.WriteLine("Content type is " + request.ContentType.ToString());
            request.ContentLength = PostData.Length;
            using (var postStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                postStream.Write(PostData);
            }
        }
```